# Unable to access vsftp server via browser, configured on centos 7

Tags: centos, vsftpd

I have configured vsftpd server on centos 7 and it is working pretty well on localhost (centos 7 machine). But when I'm trying to access that ftp server in a browser from a windows machine it is not working.

```
vsftpd is working on port no 21.

[root@centos ~]# netstat -tulpn |grep 21
tcp6       0      0 :::21      :::*                    LISTEN      29312/vsftpd
```

How to access it from a browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grep output from ps indicates that vsftpd is indeed listening on port 21, but possibly only on IPv6. If your Windows machine (and ftp client) are not using IPv6, that could be the problem.

If your vsftpd.conf file contains a listen_ipv6 directive, comment it out. Make sure you have a listen directive.

Comment: I have commented # listen_ipv6=YES and one listen directive is set to ON, but still unable to connect.

Comment: Have you just done this? If so, what is the netstat output now?

Comment: Here it is >  tcp   0      0 0.0.0.0:21     0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN      32172/vsftpd

Comment: Do you have a pasv_enable entry in vsftpd.conf? If so, it should probably be set to YES. If you don't have one, YES is the default so it's not a problem.
Another question: when you say it doesn't work from Windows in a browser. what does 'doesn't work' actually mean? How does it behave?
Have you tried it from a browser on the machine running vsftpd?

Comment: Yes it is accessible via browser on centos machine. But on windows it is asking password authentication, and after that it shows connection not established.

Comment: What username are you using? If any?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61827/discussion-between-harsh-sharma-and-bob-eager).

Comment: I'm not going to be here all the time now. So probably better to continue here.  Apart from what I asked about usernames, have you tried to FTP from the command line in Windows?

Comment: it is working via windows command line

Comment: So, what username (if any) are you using in the browser? And which browser are you using on each machine?

Comment: firefox on both the machines user= ftpuser

Comment: So ftpuser is set up as a user on the UNIX machine? And it has a password?
If so, then using  
`ftp://ftpuser:password@name.of.web.host` 
ought to work